# Unexpected result when looping chars in C++

Tags: c++, char, cout, post-increment

I'm using the book "Programming Principles and Practice using C++" to learn programming and one of the exercises is looping through the characters a-z using a while-loop.

Now, I have programmed with C++ and other languages before, so I decided to try to use as few lines as possible (while still using a while-loop). However, this came with the cost of my output being kind of messed up.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    char ch = 'a';
    while(ch <= 'z')
        std::cout << ch << '\t' << (int) ch++ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
b   97
c   98
d   99
e   100
...
x   119
y   120
z   121
{   122
```

Now I do realize that this could've been done with a for-loop instead, and I did that as well (it worked). But I still don't get what's wrong with this code, and it's really annoying me.

It appears as if I've told it to output "ch+1", since it prints out 'b' where it should print 'a'. The incrementing isn't done until after the integer value of ch has been put into the out-stream (post-increment). And even if I had incremented it earlier, at least the printed characters and their integer values should correspond.

Any ideas of why this code isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that you have a bit of Undefined Behavior because you're both modifying and using the value of the variable `ch`, via separate sub-expressions, in the same expression.

The Right Thing(TM) to do here is to use the most practical loop for the task at hand:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++a){
        std::cout << ch << '\t' << ch+0 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep adding "cheers & hth" _back_ into all your posts? You've been here for over a year, so you must have read the FAQ at least once. We do not write taglines and signatures on Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I should add that this won't work as intended for EBCDIC character encoding.

Comment: @Tomalak: it's not a signature. don't know about "tagline". anyway, it's the way i've been writing posts for like 20 years. some rather destructive aspects of SO it is necessary to conform to, but this one, designed to make the interactions more machine-like, not.

Comment: @Alf: if it helps provide rationale, this isn't a post, it's an answer to a question. Would you sign a magazine article this way, if it were written in response to a reader question? Are magazine house styles "designed to make the interactions more machine-like"? Not to say that the SO guidelines are identical to magazine guidelines, just that this is something they have in common.

Comment: @Steve: "this isn't a post, it's an answer to a question" is incorrect. it's both. "Would you sign a magazine article this way", no, I have not. "Are magazine house style...", depends on the magazine and concrete house styles. Cheers & hth., ;-)

Comment: Out of interest, which magazines have house styles that are designed with the goal of making things "more machine-like"? I'm curious to know what might be going through the minds of those editors.

Comment: @Steve: i can't help you with that question, sorry. even though it might seem to you that i'm an expert on magazines & their house styles, really i'm not. i didn't bring up that topic: you did.

Comment: @Alf: ah, your statement that it depends on the magazine suggested to me that you thought that there were some.

Comment: @steve: regarding the magazine house styles, it's the same as asking whether caucasians are intelligent. it depends on the individual. cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf: so you know that there *are* some intelligent caucasians, you just can't for the moment think of any?

Comment: Think about it logically, Alf. The answer to the question "what colour is the sky?" is "the sky is blue". The answer is not "the sky is blue, hope that helps, thanks". This is really very obvious. In _conversation_ you may wish to tag your response _after_ the answer, but on SO we are not having conversations but just giving the answers. How any software developer can "not get this" is beyond me. (And why you think "I've been doing it for 20 years" is in any way relevant is, also, beyond me.)

Comment: ["Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures), and that's the end of it. Please comply.

Comment: @Tomalak: This is the second time where you are annoyed or pretend to be annoyed beyond reason, by things that have no annoyance-factor. I don't recall what the other was, but it caused me to "ignore" you in the chat here. So your wishes are not going to be granted, sorry. :-)

Comment: @Alf: That something does not annoy _you_ does not mean that it does not annoy others. This is not in the FAQ just for fun. Please try to think beyond yourself! Your continued refusal to follow community guidelines is certainly an "annoyance-factor". Not a good example for a 14.6k rep user to set!

Comment: you are greeting your neighbours, showing good manners! that's strictly verboten! halt, or be shot! he he. don't you see how ridiculous it is? anyway, lemme tell you, we have manged quite well with allowing greetings and salutations and so on over in [comp.lang.c++.moderated], never a problem with that, so I dare say your "not for fun" argument is at best a little construed. cheers,

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum in the same way that a newsgroup or mailing list is. These arguments have been held many, many times, and the consensus was that taglines are to be removed, hence the entry in the FAQ, with which you shall abide or be forever loathed!

Comment: (And I don't see why you think it's good manners when you do it as a knee-jerk action over 20 years. It's not as if you can _actually_ mean anything by it in that case. Just make it implicit instead: of course you "hope it helps", or else you would not have posted it!)

Answer (score 5):

The order of the `operator<<` calls is well-specified, but the order in which their operands is evaluated is not.

The increment of `ch` may happen before or after you output `ch` "the first time", and merely running this program is Undefined anyway because of the interleaved read/write operations:

> `[2003: 1.9/12]:` A *full-expression* is an expression that is not a
>   subexpression of another expression. [..]
>
> `[2003: 1.9/16]:` There is a sequence point at the completion of
>   evaluation of each *full-expression*.
>
> `[2003: 5/4]:` Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands
>   of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions,
>   and the order in which side effects take place, is unspecified.
>   Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall
>   have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to
>   determine the value to be stored. The requirements of this paragraph
>   shall be met for each allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a
>   full expression; **otherwise the behavior is undefined.**

---

Instead, be explicit:

```
std::cout << ch << '\t' << int(ch) << std::endl;
++ch;
```

---

Your compiler should have warned you about your code. That it didn't indicates that you do not have your diagnostics set at a useful level.

With GCC, use `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++98 -pedantic` (or `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x -pedantic` for C++0x).

Comment: Or use a for-loop. It'll be the same number of lines, but more characters on one of those lines.

Answer (score 2):

The ch++ in your code gets evaluated first. A more readable and correct version would be:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    char ch = 'a';
    while(ch <= 'z') {
        std::cout << ch << '\t' << int(ch) << std::endl;
        ++ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unspecified whether it happens first or second, though your suggested code fix is correct.

Comment: Yes, in his case it gets evaluated first, obviously. I try to refrain from using ++ in complex expressions, since it's hard to tell what things will be evaluated when (even if specified by the standard).

Comment: Your answer implies that the `ch++` will _always_ get evaluated first, which is misleading. In fact, _anything can happen_ when this code is executed, including black holes.

Comment: Allright. Maybe we should point out, that the OP can get this information himself, when running his compiler with suitable warning flags. I just found that g++ even checks for this kind of behavior:
`$ g++ -Wall foo.cc`
`foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:`
`foo.cc:5: warning: operation on ‘ch’ may be undefined`

Comment: Indeed. In fact, you should be using `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++98 -pedantic` or `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x -pedantic`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use one variable twice in one command or expression, once with ++ (or --) and once without, you get undefined behavour.

Instead use:

```
while(ch <= 'z')
{
   std::cout << ch << '\t' << (int) ch << std::endl;
   ch++;
}
```